# what is the actual type of object parameter in vote method of spring security access decision voter

Tags: java, spring-security

I am currently working on a simple role based access control in Spring. I am using an implementation of AccessDecisionVoter. So i wonder what is the Object o parameter in the

```
public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object o, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) {
```

method? Spring documentation says it is "the secured object". I use intercept-urls and this voter gets called, so is it a controller? Or is it just a string of the url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security 3.1 `AccessDecisionVoter` should already be generic, with `<S>` parameter used as second argument in vote method. You can browse AccessDecisionVoter implementations source code (for ex. [`WebExpressionVoter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebExpressionVoter.html) which implements `AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>`) to understand the concept. Some of these implementations uses Object as generic parameter because they don't need to use secured object at all (for ex. [`RoleVoter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html)).

In your case what you probably need is to override `supports(Class<?>)` method (from docs: It *indicates whether the AccessDecisionVoter implementation is able to provide access control votes **for the indicated secured object type**.*) to get [`FilterInvokation`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/FilterInvocation.html) as secured object like `WebExpressionVoter` does:

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isAssignableFrom(FilterInvocation.class);
}
```

and then your vote implementation could be:

```
@Override
public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi,
    Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
  String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
  // rest of code, you can also fetch request / response from fi
```

Comment: thanks man, i ve printed the object and it showed me that it is infact FilterInvocation object.