# How can i get the url to be fetched in AccessDecisionVoter implementation of vote method?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for role based access controls for urls that are matching with controllers.

I want to create a system where some of the urls are checked for a users permissions. I have already created a custom access decision voter and using it in a custom access decision manager. But up to now I could not have been able to get the actual urls I want to check.

Is it possible for an access decision voter to get the actual url that is being voted? Can i use the Object o parameter specified in the vote interface method?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I responded your question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402701/708434). Basically implement `AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>`, override `supports(Class<?> clazz)` to return true only for [`FilterInvocation`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/FilterInvocation.html) objects and in vote method second parameter you'll have `FilterInvocation` object with `getRequestUrl()` method which is what you are looking for.